# Warning: validateDOMNesting(…): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, navigation, react-router-dom

I'm using React router dom Link component. It is basically twitter's home feed. I want to be able to have two type of Links in one div component. One will be Link to go to user's profile and other one to go to post. I am currently getting warning and couldn't find solution for now. Here is the screenshot as reference:

[image]

I understand the issue here, my post Link is the parent element and I've added two user Link components inside of it as the user should be able to access post page when he clicks on anything inside of the post except user's profile photo and user's name. Is there any smarter way of achieving this and keeping links like this?

Code:

```
{posts?.map((post) => (
          <Link
            className={classes.link}
            key={post.user.id}
            to={`/posts/${post.id}`}
          >
            <div className={classes.post}>
              <Link to={`/users/${post.user.id}`}>
                <img
                  className={classes.profileImage}
                  src={DefaultLogo}
                  alt="default-profile"
                />
              </Link>
              <article className={classes.postDetails}>
                <Link
                  className={classes.link}
                  to={`/users/${post.user.id}`}
                >
                  <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={`${classes.postTitle} ${classes.content}`}
                  >
                    {post.user.name}
                  </Typography>
                </Link>
                <Typography
                  variant="subtitle1"
                  className={`${classes.postText} ${classes.content}`}
                >
                  {post.body}
                </Typography>
              </article>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, having anchor tags inside of another anchor tag is misleading a bad approach to doing things. But given your requirements you can make use of a basic button with react router dom history api.

**A simple example:**

```js
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
  const history = useHistory()


  return (
     <a
      href='/user/1'
     >
       <h2>John doe</h2>
       <div>here are some use information</div>
       {/* Need to prevent the event bubbling */}     
       <Link role='link' to='/users/1/posts'>
           User posts
       </Link> 
     </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. This is reinventing links (the wrong way) just to silence a React error. The comment is also incorrect as that only works if you use `<a>`. Never nest active elements that do completely different things and never use `<div onClick>` as it's not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's utilize a dedicated **navigation handler function**. We'll swap out those pesky `<Link>` tags with `<p>` tags and wire up the `onClick` event handler to the `<p>` tags. We'll also harness the mighty `useNavigate` React hook, which conveniently supports state passing to other components during navigation.

Here is a revamped component example:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const NestedLinkSolution = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleNavigation = (event: React.MouseEvent, childRoute: string) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    navigate(childRoute);
  };

  return (
      <p
        onClick={(event) => {
          handleNavigation(event, "/parentRoute");
        }}>

         {/* Initial parts of the component */}

        <p
          onClick={(event) => {
            handleNavigation(event, "/childRoute");
          }}>

             Goto Child Route

        </p>

        {/* rest of the component */}

    </p>
  );
};

export default NestedLinkSolution;
```

With this approach, not only will you solve the issue, but you'll also infuse a dash of style into your code.