# Getting the "<a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>." error, but not quite sure how to structure my code to avoid this warning

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, warnings

This is happening inside of a Reddit clone I've created. If you use Reddit, you might recall that when you're on a feed page, you can click a post to go to the post's page. You can also click on the post author's username, which then goes to that user's profile page.

To achieve this, I've done the following. My code isn't actually structured quite like this; I put the relevant components together to show what I'm talking about, and this is a massively condensed version of the real thing:

```
<NavLink to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
    <SinglePost>
        <div>
            <SinglePostAuthorBar>
                <div>
                    <NavLink to={`/c/${community?.id}`}>c/{community?.name}</NavLink>
                </div>
            </SinglePostAuthorBar>
        </div>
    </SinglePost>
</NavLink>
```

As you can see, this leads to me having an `a` tag nested inside of another `a` tag.

Any suggestions on how I can do this so that I'm not breaking this rule or what-have-you? For example, is there a way I can link to the user's profile page on a button click or something? At the moment, I'm not sure how else I can do this. I need the user to be able to click on the entire post to be linked to the post's page, and I also need the user to be able to click on the author's username to be linked to the author's profile page.

Thanks!

**Edit**: The only other similar question I've found on here is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409964/warning-validatedomnesting-a-cannot-appear-as-a-descendant-of-a?rq=2), but the answer has a commenter saying that the answer is  actually bad practice. However, the question contains an image that shows the structure of the thing that is essentially causing the problem I've run into as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate the click behavior of the nested link instead of using a native `<a>` tag. Obviously this is [discouraged unless necessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/roles/link_role) (which it is in your case).

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

/* ... */

const navigate = useNavigate();
const communityHref = `/c/${community?.id}`;

return (
  <NavLink to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
    <SinglePost>
      <div>
        <SinglePostAuthorBar>
          <div>
            <span
              onClick={(e) => {
                // prevent parent link from triggering
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                e.preventDefault();
                navigate(communityHref);
              }}
              data-href={communityHref}
              tabIndex={0}
              role="link"
            >
              c/{community?.name}
            </span>
          </div>
        </SinglePostAuthorBar>
      </div>
    </SinglePost>
  </NavLink>
);
```

Comment: nit: I think it's slightly better for a11y if the inner links are the real anchor elements, and the other element is the "fake" one, especially if there are multiple inner links

Comment: @llllvvuu I don't necessarily agree because then both the parent and the child link needs an event listener, in the case that the parent element is "fake" the child links will also need to be default prevented to avoid triggering the parent's event. Is your opinion based on any sources or just a preference?

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `useHistory()` instead, but I got the gist of it.

Comment: @Asplund it's for a11y reasons, if you have one parent element and n child elements and only the parent is <a> then most of the functions are undiscoverable to disabled users (also non-disabled users that use browser extensions to click links). Also, the outer onClick behavior is generally more "optional" in the sense that the user can do the same action on an inner link. So it's better all the inner links are discoverable. Having to `.stopPropagation()` might be a minor inconvenience for developers, but the users are more important.

Comment: @Asplund As far as a source on the convention, both Twitter and Reddit use <a/>s inside of <div/>s. Semantically, a post is a block so it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr change the outer `<NavLink />` to a `<div onClick={router.push(nextPage)} />`**

### Some tips on reverse engineering sites like Reddit

In Reddit, the post is a `<div>` with an `onClick` handler. You can verify this in Google Chrome / Chromium-based browsers as follows (as of 2023-07-21).

1. Right click a post -> Inspect Element, and go up until you find the element that has seems responsible for the click handler (i.e. the element containing it doesn't link to the next page). What can help with this is right-clicking the element and "Store as global variable"
   in the JavaScript console and calling `temp1.click()`.

   - As of 2023-07-21, this is the `<div />` with `data-testid="post-container"` (this is used for things like testing-library or Puppeteer). You can quickly jump to one of these with Ctrl-F in the Elements tab.
2. We already have enough evidence that it's the `<div />` which is the link, but we can go further and check out the "Event Listeners" tab, where we can remove all of the click handlers and verify that the `<div />` is no longer responding to `.click()`. We can even figure out which handler specifically is responsible for responding to `.click()`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `router.push()` is a method from Next.js, which I'm not using for this project.

Comment: You'll need to use the equivalent function for whatever routing framework you're using, it's probably different for React Router, Expo Router, etc, but all routers have such a function. If you specify in the question where <NavLink /> comes from / what router you're using someone can give an exact answer otherwise you can search it up.

Comment: Is this answer [AI generated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)? OP did not ask for tips on reverse engineering

Comment: It's not AI generated. OP asked how Reddit did something, and I figured it out. I actually don't believe AI is able to do this (the current Reddit DOM is probably created after 2021)

Comment: @llllvvuu gotcha, just checking because there are a lot of AI generated answers that veer off topic